# Crashing in iOS 8 when calling UIGraphicsEndPDFContext while creating pdf

Tags: ios, iphone, pdf, ios8

Below is what I use for my application. This is working just fine in iOS 7 but crashes in iOS 8.

Using this method I take the screenshot and create the pdf and send it by an email.

```
-(void)createPDFfromUIView:(UIView*)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename
{
    // Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData
    [aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();


    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:30.0/255.0 green:172.0/255.0 blue:254.0/255.0 alpha:1]];


    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailer setSubject:@"Payment Receipt"];

        [mailer addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",aFilename]];
        NSString *emailBody = @"Payment Receipt";
        [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
        [[mailer navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];


        [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email error!"
                                                        message:@" You do not have an email address configured in your device"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }


}
```

When I add the Exception breakpoint I can see that it stops at `UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()`

Have been trying to find solution last 3 days with no success.

Comment: Did you find the 'send mail' part of your code (and question) is relevant to the error?

Comment: They are not part of the error. But no harm in placing full code as it gives full visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I used and it works.

```
-(NSData *) createPDFDataFrom:(UIView *) aView 
{
    // Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData

    [aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
    return pdfData;
}
```

Then in  another spot in your code:

// Create email opition

```
        MFMailComposeViewController * mailVC = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [mailVC setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@",@"Report",self.graphicContainer.graphicContainerName]];

        [mailVC addAttachmentData:[self createPDFDataFrom:self.baseView] mimeType:@"pdf" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",@"Report"]];
        [self presentViewController:mailVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        [mailVC release];
```

Comment: This didn't work for me too. Couldn't figure out issues. I placed a check point for iOS 8 and for them I'll send jpeg image as attachment.